# C# Getting subelement with lambda expression || CS8600 prevent null value

Tags: c#, lambda, warnings

I'm writing function in C# and one part of it should get a custom class element with specific property, namely:

Part of function:

```
tempSegment = allSegments.Find(segment =>
{
   List<Node> nodes = segment.Nodes;

   return nodes.Contains(currentNode) && nodes.Contains(nextNode);
});
```

this should find the RoadSegment type element with given Node type elements: currentNode and nextNode. Now the problem is that I get warning about possible null value element and I would rather like to prevent this: How to prevent CS8600? Is there any other way to achieve this?

RoadSegment class:

```
public class RoadSegment
{
    public double Length { get; set; }

    public double MaxSpeed { get; set; }

    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can try putting it into a try-catch block

Comment: Actually I thought about it, but as far as it handles the possible exception, it does not resolve the problem that this exception may occur. I want to prevent the occurrence of any exception rather than handling it.

Comment: Is this .Net 6.0? In 6.0 `nullable reference types` are introduced. You can disable that in your project settings but it's better to take a look at that enhancement. You probably get a null reference warning on the `nodes` variable at the point where you use the `.Contains()` method. Testing for null would solve that warning. The compiler can't determine if a value is present and issues the warning. Does that help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the expression/variable has no null value you can use the [! null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)

Quoted from docs:

> Available in C# 8.0 and later, the unary postfix ! operator is the null-forgiving, or null-suppression, operator. In an enabled nullable annotation context, you use the null-forgiving operator to declare that expression x of a reference type isn't null: x!. The unary prefix ! operator is the logical negation operator.